# Does a bijection that preserves collinearity have to be affine?

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

> Consider a bijection between two affine spaces of the same dimension $n$ (let's assume $n\ge 1$ to avoid trivialities) which sends any three collinear points into collinear points.
>
> Must such a map be affine?

I proved this with additional assumption that the affine ratio of these three points is preserved, but it seems much harder in the general case.

Comment: Certtainly not if the dimension is $1$

Comment: Why sir? I In my views, it's obvious with the 1-dimension case.
i've done it within the assumption the affine ratio of these 3 points is preserved, but it seems much harder with the above case.

Comment: This is called a **collineation**. A bijective collineation of a real affine space of dimension $\ge 2$ is affine; quoting from page 94 [of this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=trlsrl4mF3YC) where it is said that the proof is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be proven by induction and the case for two dimensions seem most technical.

First we note that a bijective collineation will map parallell hyperplanes to parallell hyperplanes. Then we note that since composing with an affine mapping will not alter anything. This means that we can assume that the mapping maps hyperplanes parallell to the $x=0$ hyper plane to hyperplanes parallell to $x=0$ and that it maps origin to origin.

For two dimension this means that we can reduce the problem to the mapping $(x,y)\to f(x), g(x)$. Since we can scale axes we can assume that $(1,1)\to f(1), g(1) = (1,1)$ so we have by collinearity that $(x,x)\to f(x), g(x)$ being on the line $x-y=0$ so $f(x)=g(x)$. Then by considering lines through $(0,1)$ and $(x, 0)$ together with the intermediate point $(x/(x+1), x/(x+1)$ you can conclude that $f(x) = x$.

Then one can use induction for the rest as the mapping can after composition be written as $(x, u)\to f(x), L(u)$ where $L(u)$ is a linear mapping of the hyperplanes and $f(x)$ is some mapping and since the line through origin and $(1,1,\cdots,1)$ have to map to a line we see that $f(x)$ must be linear.

For the cases you omit the situation is obvious, but for the record I mention that for dimension $0$ all mappings are affine so it's true there, but for dimension $1$ it's **not** since any mapping are preserving collinearity, but not all bijective mappings are not affine.

Comment: " For two dimension this means that we can reduce the problem to the mapping (x,y)→f(x),g(x)."

I don't think this statement is true. I think g can depend on both x and y even if the function sends vertical lines to vertical lines. Consider F(x,y) = (x,y+x) for example.